# save python visualization panel as html

Tags: python, panel, holoviews

I am working on Panel along with Holoviews. I would like to save it to the HTML file so that I can call it from my website. 
Following [this](https://panel.holoviz.org/user_guide/Deploy_and_Export.html), I found that the panel is able to save the file in HTML format. However, it is static and does not reflect changes based on the other components.

```
panel.save()
```

I am not able to save it even to JSON as described in the same link through this command

```
panel.embed().save_path(default='./holoviews-examples')
```

Any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting the docs a little bit, `save_path` is not a method, it's an argument to the `embed` and `save` methods, e.g.:

```py
panel.save('test.html', embed=True)
```

If you then want to export to JSON files you can also enable that with:

```py
panel.save('test.html', embed=True, embed_json=True)
```

and optionally provide a `save_path` and `load_path`.